# How do you use regex in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, scripting

I'm getting stuck on something very basic with using regex in a bash script. I'm trying to use regex to cut off .mkv, .avi, or .mp4 and assign it to a variable. I will then use this variable to create a folder, and then move the file into the folder.

I've tried:

```
folder="movie1.mkv" =~ "^\.mkv"
```

But when I run it, it complains:  `=~: command not found`

I've also tried:

```
kREGEX='^\.mkv'
folder="movie1.mkv"
[[ $folder =~ $kREGEX ]]
```

Can someone show a complete but simple script that uses regex for assigning a matched pattern to a variable?

Comment: In this case, you really need parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash:

```
folder="movie1.mkv"
[[ "$folder" =~ (.*)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

> This compares content of variable `$folder` with a regex. `(.*)\.` saves all (`.*`) before a dot (`\.`) to field 1 of array BASH_REMATCH. If regex matches, print content of `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

Output:

```
movie1
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: That worked like a charm. Unfortunately I don't know exactly how it works but I see you've linked some documentation that I can read. Any explanation would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp for this, use a parameter expansion operator:

```
filename=movie1.mkv
folder=${filename%.mkv}
echo "$folder"
```